# How can i reference a specifical input from an external indicator as an input in my new indicator in TradingView Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, indicator

I am currently trying to write an indicator in trading view that pulls in an input from another indicator existing on the chart.

I have got this working using the code

HPDRUpperRange = input(close, title="HPDRUpperRange1")

However, every time I update the indicator i lose the selection as you would expect and have to manually select it again.

I would ideally like to select the specific option directly instead of using "close" but i don't know how/if i can reference it.

[Input Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV6Zw.png)

I have added the input screenshot so you can see what it is listed as in the drop down.  If i try to reference it though it fails.

Does anyone know if its possible to hardcode it or am i stuck with manual selection each time i update the indicator?

For reference, i am tweaking the other settings a lot to test the strategy which is why it requires constant reselection.

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that as it would be throwing errors for other users or when you don't have that indicator on your chart etc.

Default value can be one of the following:

```
open/high/low/close/hl2/hlc3/ohlc4/hlcc4
```